Inconsistent behaviour for accessing COPC from S3 compatible storage
We are experiencing inconsistent behaviour on access to COPC files from Web clients. Desktop clients (QGIS and PDAL info) work perfectly from our CEPH-based S3 compatible bucket.
But https://viewer.copc.io/validator/index.html and the viewer report "failed to fetch".
The response is an expected 206 ( not all of our files return a 206).
I am wondering whether settings of the S3 storage may be affecting this.

Works for me https://viewer.copc.io?state=259504e40bf576cb4a630f331ec712fc2932f370d2054c16a0046d23bd6abcf6

This has been solved by activating the S3 CORS policy on the S3 bucket:
aws s3api put-bucket-cors --endpoint-url YOURS3URL --bucket BUCKETNAME --cors-configuration '{"CORSRules" : [{"AllowedHeaders":["*"],"AllowedMethods":["GET","HEAD"],"AllowedOrigins":["*"],"ExposeHeaders":["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]}]}'


I will reword the question too.
